# Delphi 7 TWebBrowser - how to exit it

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I have developed a Delphi prog which logs into a website, collects "today's number" and displays it on a screen. Having got the data, the only place I could access it was in the final 'download completed' event. This doesn't seem right, as there seems to be no way to get away from the string of 'completed' events. The program never returns from the WB.Navigate call.   WB.Stop and WB.Quit seem to refer to browser activity. I want a WB.TERMINATE or something! It's OK for now, but I want to put the web access in a loop, and with the current technique it just burrows deeper into the stack etc. I assume it's running in a separate thread, but can find no info about this. Should I put the browser component on a separate form created at run-time? Would freeing the form tidy things up? Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks for early responses. I must have had a senior moment. In fact the WB.Navigate call *does* return. The IDE tells me that it launched a thread with the web navigation request. So it's down to me to do some internal synchronizing to check the data arrival. Yes, the data is on the web page not a download. There is no API. I could have done basic searching of the web pages but it's 3 levels deep. The component made it easier to select the wanted data. All good now. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: First off, does't that site have an API that you could use without faking user's input with a browser ?

Comment: Can you mention the site and show some code? Maybe we can take a look...

Comment: Sounds like you need a simple http download, or perhaps a headless browser if there is JS involved

Comment: Sorry, can't quite follow your description.  Is the number you're after displayed on the web page, or contained in some file you're downloading from it?